# Android facebook isn't able to send/post to a friend using SDK 4.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here,I'm getting logged into the app using facebook account using 4.1. But now I want to send message to a friend or post something to a friend's wall but I'm not getting a proper answer for doing it.

```
onCreate(){
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
 .
 .
  loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends","publish_actions"));
}

loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Error");
        }
    });

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // manage login results
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to post to a friend’s timeline or send them a message via API. You can however bring up the Send dialog for the user of your app, or connect to the Facebook messenger.

Comment: @CBroe You mean we can use only native apps of Facebook?

Comment: I have checked it for messages https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat but now I want to know we can post anything on a user's wall or not.

Comment: Sure you can post to the wall of the user that is using your app. But be aware, that the user must write the message himself, your app is not allowed to specify it for them, and that you are only allowed to post when it is actively triggered by the user each time – no “autoposting” allowed.

Comment: Can you please provide me any source code for doing it?